# Getting all return values of a query in one cell / row?

Tags: mysql

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM catalog_product_flat_1 e
   LEFT JOIN catalog_category_product ccp
          ON ccp.product_id = e.entity_id
   INNER JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar AS ccev
           ON ccp.category_id = ccev.entity_id
   WHERE e.entity_id = 1234567
```

It gets all categories for a product with SKU 1234567. If the product is in multiple categories, there will be one row for each category.

How could I display the results in one row only? I want a column called `categories` that contain all values, separated with a comma. I tries this and that with `CONCAT`, but did not succeed. Is that possible at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Use group_concat() and group by

Comment: group_concat did the job!

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).